# How to config mail.php to send emails to the real address in production, not in development?

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 8.

My app sends emails. In development , I configured my **email.php** like that (extract) :

```
   'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],


'to' => [
    'address' => 'xxxxx.yyyy@domain.com',
    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

Like that, when I am in development , all the emails are sent to xxxx.yyyy@domain.com. It is very useful, BUT I have to remember before each deployment to comment this entry "to".

My question is : how to write something elegant in this config file to allow the sending to the real email when the environment is production, otherwise sending must be done to xxxx.yyyy@domain.com ?

*I know I can send the email to a log file. But it is not useful to see the real email. I am looking for another solution.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply fetch the `env` field and make your logic from that. Offcourse your production environment has to run on the correct production `env`.

```
'address' => env('APP_ENV') === 'PRODUCTION' ? 'real.email@domain.com' : 'fake.email@domain.com'
```

Comment: An alternative to this would be keeping .env in separate files (like .env.dev and .env.prod) and using symbolic links to .env. That way you can make changes on one spot without having to deal with various config files.